# iOS Endless Runner Lag SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an iOS endless runner game where the path appears from the top and scrolls down.

Here's how I do it: 2 sprites are created and when the first one disappears from the screen, I load another sprite from an image and run the same logic.

The problem: There's a small lag right after the first sprite disappears and the new one appears.

Edit: This problem only occurs when running on iPhone 5. iPhone 4 works perfectly !

Anyone have any ideas? or has run into this problem before and solved it?

```
if (CurrentObstacle.frame.origin.y < -self.frame.size.height + 10) {

    //  clear old obstacle
    CurrentObstacle = nil;

    CurrentObstacle = nextObstacle;
    currentObstacleImage = nextObstacleImage; // for pixel processing stuff

    [self generateObstacle];
}

- (void)generateObstacle{

// genrate random image name
int i = rand()%10+1;
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ob%i", i];
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
if(screenSize.height == 480)
{
    //Load 3.5 size
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"small"];
}
imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];


// create obstacle
nextObstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:imageName];
nextObstacleImage = [imageDictionary objectForKey:imageName];
nextObstacle.size = self.size;
nextObstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 1.48*nextObstacle.size.height);

// set speed to be the same as the other obstacles
nextObstacle.speed = CurrentObstacle.speed;

// show obstacle
[self addChild:nextObstacle];

// move obstacle
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-2*self.size.height-1 duration:8];
[nextObstacle runAction:moveAction];
}
```

Comment: Pre-load them so that you always have the next one loaded at any given time.

Comment: At least post the code you run to swap the sprites. If we can't see what exactly you're doing we can't diagnose it.

Comment: I just added the code.
@SantaClaus I don't think it's the issue, I think the problem has to do with with the objects appearing on the screen. Because it works fine on iPhone 4. But not with iPhone 5.

Comment: @SantaClaus , I just tried your suggestion. There's still a noticeable lag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved this problem by removing the @2x images. Apparently processing big images was the cause of the lag.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't load the image each time you want to add an obstacle. You should do a methode like this that you would call at "initWithSize"

```
//MyScene.h
@interface MyScene : SKScene{
SKTexture * textureObstacle1;
SKTexture * textureObstacle2;
//...//
}
-(id)initWithSize;
-(void)LoadSprites;
@end


//MyScene.m
@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
[self LoadSprites];
}
return self;
}

-(void)LoadSprites{
textureObstacle1=[[SKTexture alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"obstacle1.png"];
//...//
}
- (void)generateObstacle{
//...//
nextObstacle = [SKSpriteNode alloc]init];
[nextObstacle setTexture:textureObstacle1];
}
@end
```